# Best place in spec/ for integration responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have some integration points where I want to test various responses - where do you think should I store these artifacts in my spec/ directory of my rails application?

Comment: This question is unclear. What do you mean by artifacts? Provide more detailed description of what you're doing and maybe some examples.

Also, don't try to have a conversation in the "answers" area because answers should be, well, *answers*, and keep in mind that they aren't sorted by date.

Comment: I believe that the artifacts are the responses - the "expected"s, to use a common phrase.  These are too large to include in the test definition itself, and thus become data files tied to specific tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've created a test/resources or spec/resources directory for other test/spec related files.  That seems to keep it clear that it's some sort of other file used only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

you could just create a spec/fixtures dir and stick em in there.